# What is difference between Impulse and Thrust in Physics/Rocket Science?

Tags: rocket-science

The question is clear.
What is the difference between Impulse and Thrust in Physics/Rocket Science as meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NASA](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/specimp.html):

> The total impulse (I) of a rocket is defined as the average thrust **times** the total time of firing. ...Since the thrust may change with time, we can also define an integral equation for the total impulse.

---

As a rough analogy for the relationship, you can think of thrust being like the amount of a monthly payment on a house or car, maybe even with occasional extra payments, and impulse being like the total price of buying that house/car.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. Is this actual difference or your think?

Comment: @MuhammedÇ.TUFAN Do you think of NASA as a reliable source for basic information about rocket science? (I generally do.)

Comment: Yeah, I do. I don't have very good English. Sorry for misunderstand. Have a good day!